# Download the image only once in getView() method of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of images (with descriptions) that are downloaded from the url. Everything is ok until the time when I re scroll list to the top. Pictures are taken again because (I guess) method is called again getView (). How to make the image has been downloaded only once? Below class ArrayAdapter

```
public class ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter extends
ArrayAdapter<ImageWithTwoText> {
    public final static String TITLE_KEY = "title";
    public final static String SUBTITLE_KEY = "subtitle";
    public final static String IMAGE_RESOURCE_KEY = "imageResources";

    private final List<ImageWithTwoText> imageWithTwoTextList;
    private final Context context;

    TextView titleView;
    TextView subTitleView;
    ImageView imageView;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public ImageWithTwoTextArrayAdapter(Context context,
        List<ImageWithTwoText> imageWithTwoTextList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_view, imageWithTwoTextList);
    this.context = context;
    this.imageWithTwoTextList = imageWithTwoTextList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);

    ImageWithTwoText currentElement = imageWithTwoTextList.get(position);

    titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    subTitleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
    imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    titleView.setText(currentElement.getTitle());
    subTitleView.setText(currentElement.getSubTitle());
    if (currentElement.getImageResource() != null) {
        imageView.setImageResource(currentElement.getImageResource());
    } else {
        if (imageView.getDrawable() == null) {
        new DownloadThumbnailTask(imageView).execute(currentElement
            .getImageURI());
        }
    }

    return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this library: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: You can cache images while loading using the above library.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) tutorial for caching the images called lazy loading  , i am using it and it works like charm and just a two step process .